# How to choose pocketSphinx's language model in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I just need a speech recognition library in linux. Then I choose CMU Sphinx, and use pocketSphinx with python.  I test that [demo](http://cmusphinx.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cmusphinx/trunk/pocketsphinx/scripts/livedemo.py). This example runs well in my computer with poor accuracy.

---

I know that I need a language model, and I have downloaded it. So, How to set my pocketSphinx use that 'lm'. I mean, How to fix that demo file to use that language model. (and acoustic model.)

### Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language model is configured through the property of the pocketsphinx gstreamer component. Instead of

```
   gst.parse_launch('gconfaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample '
                    + '! vader name=vad auto-threshold=true '
                    + '! pocketsphinx name=asr ! fakesink')
```

Use

```
   gst.parse_launch('gconfaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample '
                    + '! vader name=vad auto-threshold=true '
                    + '! pocketsphinx lm=<your_file.lm> name=asr ! fakesink')
```

You can configure other properties of pocketsphinx component too. Use gst-inspect to read the list.

Comment: thank you very much! I add the dict and language model but the accuracy still not good enough. So, what should I do next?